# Constraint layout wrap content makes the view dissapear

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I am building a simple layout that has a scrollview and works with constraint layout,

I am near to have what i need, i just need to adjust 2 views left, a description title and at bottom of it the respective description.

The thing is, the element at the bottom doesn't adjust i try to wrap content on the height, since the element description can grow, but when i do that the view just dissapears and any element above that had scroll to,

Any help with this?

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />


        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/SpecieName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="adas "
            android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/googleMapsText" />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/GenreName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:onClick="genrePressed"
            android:text="asdas "
            android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.004"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/FamilyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:onClick="familyPressed"
            android:text="asdaswwww"
            android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Family"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/GenreName"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Espécie"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/SpecieName"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            tools:layout_constraintBaseline_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="58dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="Género"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/Family"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="Familia"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_heightPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="105%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/plantImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="275dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/color_cursor_white" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/plantImage"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />


        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/googleMapsText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="Ver no mapa"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gallery"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook_placeholder_for_locate_places_on_maps"
            android:tint="#F90101"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/gallery"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gallery"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="0dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="0dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteX="360dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/specieDescription"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="asdfasd "
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/descricaoTit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descricaoTit"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="120%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="90%"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/descricaoTit"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Descrição"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/Family"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Family"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**important part:**

the title:

```
<com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/descricaoTit"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Descrição"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/Family"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Family"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />
```

**the description:**

```
<com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
        android:id="@+id/specieDescription"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="asdfasd "
        android:textSize="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/descricaoTit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descricaoTit"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="120%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="90%"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

[image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqiPt.png)

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use relative layout instead of constraints when you have multiple views or widgets.

Comment: yes, but that doesn't help i already have the views and i know it is possible!

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: i shared, check image above